# Сайт на WordPress. Вид темы со скриншота этой темы и реальный вид не совпадают. Почему?

Tags: wordpress

Есть тема для WordPress, **MyKnowledgeBase**. На скриншоте во всю ширину расположена таблица категорий с постами. Я её установил и не вижу такой картинки. обычный Вордпресс в виде блога. Вроде во все настройки залез, но как превратить вид темы в такой же, не понимаю. Попробовал поставить тему mywiki, но там то же самое. На скриншоте таблица из разделов и постов, а реально просто блог.

Подскажите пожалуйста, это я туплю, или скриншот от создателей получится только если прикрутить кастомные стили? Но тогда зачем он такой нужен?

*Скриншот темы от разработчика*
[image: Скриншот темы от разработчика]

Comment: Кастомные стили не нужно прикручивать. На скриншоте обычно отображают тему с определенными настройками и набором плагинов. Обычно в документации указывают как добиться подобного вида либо добавляют в тему демо данные

Comment: Да, действительно. Я не заметил документацию, а точнее файл radme.txt, в котором указано, как создать такой вид. Если кто из гугла придёт, то это делается через установку шаблона knowledge base page template для свежесозданной страницы, которую и нужно поставить в качестве домашней. Вопрос решён.

Answer (score 2):

За картинку темы в админке отвечает файл screenshot.jpg(.png) в корне темы.

За вид темы отвечают стили, файлы темы и прочее.

То что картинка не совпадает с темой это вполне нормальное явление

Comment: Эм, это очевидно. Но суть-то в том, что мне нужен ИМЕННО этот функционал: отображение категорий и постов в них. И вроде как (судя по скриншотам) эти две темы этот функционал дают. Но реально - нет, не дают. Как-то это странно.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, это я туплю, или скриншот от создателей
>   получится только если прикрутить кастомные стили? Но тогда зачем он
>   такой нужен?

Скриншот от производителя показывает **возможный** вид  **главной страницы** будущего сайта.
И никакие кастомные стили в данном случае не нужны.

Любую, абсолютно любую тему нужно настраивать под свои задачи. А чтобы было что настраивать - на сайте должен быть контент.  Хотя бы основной, участвующий в выводе на главную и др основные страницы.

У некоторых тем есть демо-контент. Но от него может быть больше вреда чем пользы - от него потом ещё избавляться надо. Что-то упустить при этом и не заметить этого - достаточно легко. Особенно новичкам.

Comment: Я добавлял свой контент, но это не изменило вид.

Comment: Добавить контент + *настроить* тему/сайт. И в понятие "контент" входит не только текст.